# ebay transactions on bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce, ebay-api

Does anyone know how to find out if an order on Bigcommerce is an ebay listing?

I'm using the Bigcommerce API to get orders for a store, and need to identify which orders (or products within an order) are ebay listings as well..

This link details how you put your ebay listings on Bigcommerce
https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1167/Managing+your+eBay+listings+on+Bigcommerce
My question is how you identify them using the Bigcommerce API calls

thanks